# NullPointerException in ORB.getPresentationManager when calling ORB.string_to_object

Tags: java, corba, idl, tao

Admittedly I'm new to CORBA and using ORBs. I have some code that gets installed on a 3rd party machine that is using the TAO ORB version 1.3. When my code calls:

`String myObjectString = "IOR: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";`

`ORB.string_to_object(myObjectString);`

I get an exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB.getPresentationManager(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.spi.orb.ORB.getStubFactoryFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_Object(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_Object(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_Object(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.getIORFromString(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.string_to_object(Unknown Source)
    at CussClient.enableMediaOutput(CussClient.java:1232)
    at CussClient.ActivateComponents(CussClient.java:1879)
    at CussClient.setApplicationState(CussClient.java:268)
    at CussClient.HandleEvent(CussClient.java:2425)
    at evtListenerImpl.callback(evtListenerImpl.java:31)
    at types.evtListenerPOA._invoke(evtListenerPOA.java:49)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)`

This same code works on other 3rd party machines running other ORBs, so I'm not sure if this is an issue with the TAO ORB, or something else. Are there any ORB masters that can tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: What could help is to take the IOR and dump its content using the tao_catior utility. When you do that you will see that the IOR only contains localhost endpoints which means they can only be used on the same system as the server runs, are you doing that?

Comment: Looks the exception is throw from the Java code, not TAO

Comment: The IOR is also not generated by TAO, are you really using TAO in your setup?

Comment: @JohnnyWillemsen I used IDL files to build java classes, which my java applet uses to reference an orb that is running on the 3rd party machine. The owner of the machine tells me that they are using TAO. How are you able to determine where the IOR is generated from? And how can I get this tao_catior utility? I've searched for it but can't seem to find any downloadable script/executable to run it on the IOR.

Comment: When the IOR is generated with TAO I would expect a tag TAG_ORB_TYPE which is not there. The tao_catior utility is part of the TAO sources, one quick way would be to get an evaluation copy of TAOX11, that has a precompiled version of tao_catior, see http://taox11.remedy.nl

Comment: Have you tried JacORB as ORB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being caused by the JRE version that was installed on the 3rd party machine.

This was related to the airline industry CUSS (Common Use Self Service) version 1.3 requirements that state what version of Java is required to be installed. In the CUSS docs it stated that Java 1.7.0_21 and above were allowed. In the Errata docs it was changed to require Java 1.7.0_21 specifically.